# VSA in radiusrequest

Tags: linux, radius, freeradius, radius-protocol

I am using radiusclient-ng-0.5.6
in my directory ?I have added below lline for VSA attributes.
But still my radiusclient binary is not working.please help me with this.

directory

```
VENDOR  EC       20000
BEGIN-VENDOR EC
        ATTRIBUTE abc1 7777 string
        ATTRIBUTE abc2 7778 string
END-VENDOR   EC


./radiusclient -f /etc/radiusclient-ng/radiusclient.conf User-Name=aaa abc1=aaaaa
```

error:
Apr 21 22:47:53 localhost lt-radiusclient: rc_avpair_parse: unknown attribute abc1

Comment: Your `BEGIN-VENDOR` name doesn't match the `VENDOR` name, which means it's either (a) not parsing the dictionary or (b) generating an error that you're ignoring.

Comment: sorry, that was my writing mistake. updated strings are above.still getting such error. actually I don't know what should be the command line argument for VSA !!

Comment: The argument is correct, it looks like the file that contains the dictionary is not being read. Does the config entry for `dictionary` in the `radiusclient.conf` file reference the file containing the attribute? It's not as full featured as the server version which permits includes, so you need a complete list of all the attribute-value pairs (including vendor specific ones) in a single file that is read on the client startup.

Comment: yes the directory is being reffered. if I wite `ATTRIBUTE abc1 7777 string` only this, it is working properly. but I suppose to add it under vendor specific attribute. but it is give errors like.. rc_avpair_parse: unknown attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use the freeradius radiusclient library, but it's mostly the same code as what was previously developed for the `radiusclient-ng` library, but the `dictionary` file format is the same, and doesn't support the `BEGIN-VENDOR` ... `END-VENDOR` syntax, so you have to use a slightly different format.

The general format of vendor specific attributes is stated in the RFC as:

```
0                   1                   2                   3
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|     Type      |  Length       |            Vendor-Id
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
     Vendor-Id (cont)           | Vendor type   | Vendor length |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|    Attribute-Specific...
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-
```

Which means it only supports vendor types from `0` - `255`. The use of large numbers (`> 255`) is intended for internal server use and would not be an acceptable value to use for the attribute id number (i.e. `7777` and `7778` are way too big to be expected vendor types).

You've defined your vendor using the line:

```
VENDOR EC 20000
```

And now you need to specify the VSAs using the following format:

```
ATTRIBUTE abc1 7 string vendor=EC
ATTRIBUTE abc2 8 string vendor=EC
```

This specifies them with a `Vendor type` of `7` and `8` respectively.

If you're referencing the proper dictionary file, then the attributes become available to be used and can be passed in:

```
./radiusclient -f /etc/radiusclient-ng/radiusclient.conf User-Name=aaa abc1=aaaaaa abc2=bbbbb
```

Comment: To be honest though, unless you have a driving reason for using `radiusclient-ng`, I'd use `radiusclient` from the freeradius project which is (slightly) newer and has a few fixes for issues that exist in the last release of the `-ng` library

Comment: You do know that the packets are encrypted using the secret specified for the server - are you using the RADIUS dissector from wireshark and setting the secret key in the options?